How can I italicize part of a string when using ggdraw and draw_label for a plot title?
How can I italicize part of a string when using draw_label() for a title?
I am adding a ggplot plot title separately using ggdraw() and draw_label() since this is part of a for loop that plots different groups stored in lists. At the end, I put everything together using plot_grid().
My current code:
title <- ggdraw() +
    draw_label(label = paste(full_taxa_names[taxa], "in", 
                             full_region_names[Region], "\n", season), 
               size = 18) 

This gives me almost what I needed, except italics in taxa name.
I want to italicize taxa names in the title (species = full_taxa_names[taxa]).
My data:
dput(full_taxa_names)

list(ctyp = "Centropages typicus", calfin = "Calanus finmarchicus",
pseudo = "Pseudocalanus spp.")
dput(full_region_names)

list(GOM = "Gulf of Maine", MAB = "Mid-Atlantic Bight", GB = "Georges Bank",
SNE = "Southern New England")
dput(season)

c("fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall",
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall",
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall",
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall",
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall",
"fall", "fall")
class(full_taxa_names)

[1] "list"
class(full_region_names)

[1] "list"
class(season)

[1] "character"
I tried:
ggdraw() +
        draw_label(label = expression(paste(italic("full_taxa_names[taxa]"),
                                             full_region_names[Region], 
                                             "\n:", 
                                             season), 
                   size = 18)) 

which prints out "full_taxa_names[taxa]full_region_names_Region:season" instead of having the actual correct values.
I could not get it to work with bquote() either.
I tried:
ggdraw() +
  draw_label(
    label = bquote(italic(.(full_taxa_names[taxa])) ~ "in" ~ .(full_region_names[Region]) ~ "\n:" ~ .(season)),
    size = 18)

which gives "in:" [season]. So doesn't include the taxa nor region.
I tried:
ggdraw() +
  draw_label(
    label = expression(paste(italic("Taxa"), " ", full_taxa_names[taxa], " in ", full_region_names[Region], "\n: ", season)),
    size = 18)

which gives "Taxa full_names_taxa in full_region_names_Region: season" instead of the actual items.
I tried using annotate() with bquote(), also tried annotate() with expression() instead of geom_text() but could not get it to just print out the "P" in italics.
Ultimately these go into:
plot_grid(title, combined_plots, legend2, ncol = 1, 
                          rel_heights = c(0.07, 0.8, 0.07)) 

How can I properly italicize part of a string when using draw_label() and geom_text() inside of a for loop for ggplots?
UPDATE:
Based on Ric's answer, I tried the recommendation of:
ggdraw() +
  draw_label(label = bquote(paste(italic(.(full_taxa_names[taxa])),
                                  .(full_region_names[Region]),
                                  .(season))), 
                                size = 18)

which just prints the season and nothing else...
Based on Ric's suggestion, it seems like the issue lies in trying to use "\n" and having the full_taxa_names and full_region_names as a list (which I thought bquote would work with lists).
I don't mind not having two lines, so then I tried the following removing the \n and making the lists a character vector instead.
I created character vector:
  taxa1 <- as.character(full_taxa_names[taxa])
  region1 <- as.character(full_region_names[Region])

And then did:
ggdraw() +
    draw_label(label = bquote(paste(italic(.(taxa1)), " in ",
                                    .(region1), " in ",
                                    .(season))), 
               size = 18)

which gives me what I want so I have solved my problem.
I think my issue was just that bquote does not work with lists (or if it does, then I don't know how). I'm not a coder, just a student in STEM that uses R for analysis and plots, so maybe it is an obvious problem but I couldn't find a solution that worked for me in stackoverflow nor AI help until I posted this question. I often just work with data.frames() since I find them easier to use, but now trying to get more comfortable with lists and other data classes as my analyses require it.
I can include my full for loop code if it helps clarify,but it's long (results in 192 plots) and maybe not that relevant to the title problem I present here.
Updated question to focus on one problem only (italicizing) and included data.

bquote() should work.
Remember to put literal text between a dot call i.e..(full_taxa_names[taxa])
Note however that labels in plots do not accept "\n" line breaks in general, best you can is use "atop" but I think it is better to draw a new label just below. (Line break in expression()?)
Also, see ?plotmath reference
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

taxa <- 1
Region <- 1
full_taxa_names <- "<taxa>"
full_region_names <- "<region>"
season = "winter"

title <- ggdraw() +
  draw_label(label = bquote(paste(italic(.(full_taxa_names[taxa])),
                                  .(full_region_names[Region]),
                                  .(season))), 
                                size = 18) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))

title


Created on 2024-06-24 with reprex v2.1.0

good to know about the \n line breaks in plots that was likely my main issue. your suggestion worked, but I had to save the taxa names and regions as a character vector instead of using the list. full_taxa_names was originally a list of 3 and full_region_names a list of 4. can bquote not handle lists was that my issue..?

Hello. Hard to guess because we didn't see the data in your example. bquote() will handle whatever you put inside .()  . It is worth to note that bquote produces a "call" object (See  2.1.3) that is why plot labels interpret them in special form different that character vectors. A good approach is to print the result of the bquote() to see what it produces.

okay, added data. i havent worked with bquote much but it helps to know that is should handle whatever you put inside .() ! thanks!
